# Avoiding declaring private functions in class header files (C++)

Tags: c++, function, header, private, declare

(In C++) I have a class whose structure is declared in a header file. That header file is included in lots of source files, such that when I edit it I need to recompile lots of files.

The class has a set of private functions which are only called in one source file. Currently they are declared in the class structure in the header file. When I add a new function of this type, or edit the arguments, it therefore causes recompilation of lots of files. I would like to declare the functions somewhere else, such that only the file that defines and calls them is recompiled (to save time). They still need to be able to access the internal class variables, though.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There are the approaches which work well if I were writing the class from scratch. However, I'm not starting from scratch; this class is already written.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to declare member functions of a class outside the main class declaration. So, if you want to declare, outside of the class in question, functions that can access member variables of a particular instance of the class, then I see no alternative but to pass that instance to the function. Furthermore, if you want the functions to be able to access the private and protected variables you will need to put them in a new class and make the original class a friend of that. E.g.

header.h:

```
class FooImpl;

class Foo {
public:
   int bar();
   friend class FooImpl;
private:
   int var;
}
```

impl.cpp:

```
#include "header.h"

class FooImpl {
public:
   int bar(Foo &);
}

int FooImpl::bar(Foo &foo) {
return foo.var;
}

int Foo::bar() {
return FooImpl::bar(*this);
}
```

Comment: This is my understanding so far, but I'm not 100% sure. Comments gratefully received.

Comment: You still have `int var` in `class Foo`. Isnt the whole point of the question is to move it to `class FooImpl`?

Comment: @balki: No, the whole point of this question was how to add or edit private _functions_ in a class, without changing the header. If I move the private variables to FooImpl then I also have to forward all the existing public functions to that class. See my first comment to Erik's answer about that.

Answer (score 14):

Use the [pImpl idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) - Your visible class keeps a pointer to the *real* class and forwards calls to public member functions.

EDIT: In response to comments

```
// Foo.h:

class FooImpl; // Do *not* include FooImpl.h
class Foo {
public:
  Foo();
  ~Foo();
  //.. also need copy ctor and op=
  int bar();
private:
  FooImpl * Impl;
};

// FooImpl.h:

class FooImpl {
public:
  int bar() { return Bar; }
private:
  int Bar;
};

// Foo.cpp:

#include "FooImpl.h"

Foo::Foo() { Impl = new FooImpl(); }
Foo::~Foo() { delete Impl; }
int Foo::bar() { return Impl->bar(); }
```

Keep the actual implementation of your class in `FooImpl` - `Foo` should have copies of the *public* members of `FooImpl` and simply forward calls to these. All users will include only "Foo.h" - you can change all the private details of `FooImpl` without the users of `Foo` seeing any changes.

Comment: Thanks. It's a good idea in general. However, in this case I didn't start off using this framework, so moving to it would require an extensive rewrite of my class, including writing wrappers for all its public functions. I'd like to just be able to ship a subset of private functions out of the header, without too much hassle.

Comment: @user664303: Inheritance *may* be a solution - this particular problem is one of the annoying fallacies of C++ imo.

Comment: Am I right in thinking it will necessarily require a cast of the class instance pointer, e.g.: ((priv_class *)this)->priv_func();. Or is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @user664303: Forward declaration - .h: `class FooImpl; class Foo { public: void bar(); FooImpl * Impl; };` .cpp: `#include "FooImpl.h" ... void Foo::bar() { Impl->bar(); }`

Comment: @Erik: I don't get how FooImpl::bar() would have access to the private members of Foo. I could make Foo a friend of FooImpl, but I'd still have to pass FooImpl::bar() a pointer to an instance of Foo.

Comment: @user664303: Foo doesn't have private members (except the Impl pointer) - it only has the same public member functions as FooImpl. See updated answer with sample.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [Compiler Firewall](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill05.htm), a.k.a. PIMPL?

Answer (score 1):

Create an abstract base class which contains only the public functions and reference this in your headers. Create your real class as an implementation somewhere else. Only source files which need to create your class need to see the implementation class header.

Comment: Then hide the creation through a factory function